# Should I add checks for parameters which are just passed to another method?

Tags: c#, code-contracts

Consider these two methods

```
public int GetSomething(object obj)
{
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj != null);

    ...
}

public int GetSomethingWrapper(object anotherObj)
{
    var obj = GetObj(anotherObj);
    return GetSomething(obj);
}
```

Let's consider `GetObj` to be safe i.e. it doesn't throw any exceptions.
Thus `GetSomething` and `GetSomethingWrapper` throw execption if obj is null. But in the latter case the origin of exception is `GetSomething` method.

The question is whether I'd add checks for `GetSomethingWrapper`?
One the one side: not its business to care about. On the other: both methods are public but caller of the wrapper method has no contract information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One the one side: not its business to care about.

Yes it is - it's calling a method with a contract, so it ought to abide by that contract. The simplest way of abiding by that contract is to impose its own contract.

Then as you say there's the additional problem that currently `GetSomethingWrapper` has no contract, so it *should* be legitimate to call it with an null argument... but it's really not.

So basically, yes - I'd add the contract to `GetSomethingWrapper` too. The *implementation detail* that it calls `GetSomething` shouldn't affect the public contract.

Comment: That's clear. Thanks. But what if contract of the DoSomething() method will be weakened later? Thus my wrapper will impose more strict requirements. This is not terrible but not so easy to catch this situation. Unfortunately static checker doesn't warn about unnecessary checks. Any ideas concernign this problem?

Comment: @voroninp: It's up to you whether you try to make one set of contracts follow the other. You could update them both at the same time - but you *may* not want to. Basically, this is what you get for exposing functionality in a redundant way - it comes with the responsibility of thinking about it when things change. That's not to say it's a bad idea, just that it comes with the territory.